# Are two tasks with same name maintained separately in C#?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have the following code in my console application:

```
if (Count % 11 >= 5)
{
    GrabberTask = GrabberTask.ContinueWit(Grabber.ExtractSources);
}
```

The if clause is inside a loop with a counter. I want to know what happens if the if evaluates to true for a second time before the `GrabberTask` starts for the first time. Is there any better way to keep doing the same Task when the if condition evaluates to true. I am extracting the image sources from a webpage and storing them in a `LinkedList`. Sometimes I am getting duplicate links being added to the `LinkedList` from two different Tasks. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you provide a continuation, the whole continuation will be executed.

What you need is to implement some kind of *thread synchronization* to avoid more than a thread execute a given operation against some resource.

The simplest one is the `lock` statement:

```
public class Test
{
    private static readonly object _syncLock = new object();

    public void MyMethod() 
    {
         lock(_syncLock)
         {
            // No more than a thread will be able to work within this
            // protected code block. Others will be awaiting/blocked until
            // the thread that acquired the lock leaves this code block
         }
    }
}
```

Now, if you perform many continuations in some time interval that might need to execute the same thing, no more than a continuation will be able to be executed at once.

Comment: Precisely what I wanted to know. Thanks.